# Loaded plugins: fastestmirror Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile Centos 7 Error? yum update not working on new VM

Tags: linux, centos

I just installed new VM it is giving below error when i run yum update command
[root@localhost ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; Unknown error"

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64

I want to update it so i can configure what seems to be missing.

Comment: I solved issue by running following command 

vi /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but  This Q is not about `if-tnen-else` programming as defined for StackOverflow. In the future, please post these questions to [unix.se] OR [su] .  Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ,   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  ,  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.